# C# Excel 2007 late binding

Tags: c#, excel

I have this example from Microsoft which is working perfectly with Excel 2003. How can I do the same with 2007?

Please look in below the title "Create an Automation client that uses late binding"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302902

Comment: It should work in the same way. If it's not, tell us what happens.

Comment: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80028018): Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)

Comment: http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=2911

Answer (score 0):

I have Visual Studio 2010 and Excel 2010 and the code from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302902 runs perfectly.

Try stepping through the debugger to see where the error occurs.  Also, if you can try with 2010, see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

change your interop dll references from 2003 to 2007 or use latebinding for both version support.